# Apple rejected an app that for use on non public api where there aren't any non pulic apis

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, iphone-privateapi

This is the message I got from Apple for rejecting my app:

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> didDetermineState:forRegion:
>      didEnterRegion:
>      didExitRegion:
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

I really don't know what to do as there api are clearly public. Anyone got some advise? It would really help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the public apis you are mentioning about are those in [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate?language=objc). If it is the case, take `didEnterRegion:`, for example, the api is actually `locationManager:didEnterRegion:`. However, Apple mentions `didEnterRegion:` only. That probably means somewhere in your app, you have **declared** a method with that exact signature, and it happens to have the same signature with a private api method.

My suggestion is to do a search on your whole project for such methods and rename them.

Comment: Yeah.. That's most likely the case. There's this library I've used from FourSquare which has methods with that signature. I've sent in a note to Apple clarifying the issue. Hope they approve it quickly.

Thanks a lot!